# Show different custom login screens for different sets of Pentaho solutions

Tags: pentaho

I have two sets of solutions targeted at different users (say: finance and operations).  They're composed basically of CDE dashboards.

I wish to present a different Pentaho login screen for each of the solutions, to kind of show they're different "applications", or a different set of dashboards.

Can I have two customized login screens that can be invoked or switched according to a parameter? Like, say, sending &theme=newapp in the URL? Has anyone done it?

I have customized the login screen and have done themes in Pentaho, so I know the basics.

I'm using Pentaho 5.2 CE

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this by changing the back-ground image of the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the login redirect filter. Everytime you hit a Pentaho URL and don't have a valid session you're sent to the Pentaho/Login page.

So you have two options: change the redirect class so that it redirects to different login pages depending on the URL or have the referral URL parsed by the login page and display different content depending on where the user came from.

Neither of these options is easy, though.

Comment: Got it. So you think that in any case I would have to change or create a class? Do you reckon it can be done by changing some spring configuration, or perhaps PUCLogin.jsp?

Comment: to redirect to different login pages based on URL I believe you will need to edit or create a new class to be called by Spring; to do it via the referral, it should suffice to change PUCLogin.jsp.